# Find consecutive space delimited single characters in each line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, perl, awk, sed

Let say I have the following file

```
Y M C A
cambridge m a
d m v office
t mobile
```

and want to convert it to

```
YMCA
cambridge ma
dmv office
t mobile
```

that is to detect all consecutive single characters followed by single space of different lengths ( greater than two). For example, the item 'd m v office', we should detect **'d m v'** and convert it to **'dmv'** but would leave 't mobile store' intact (only one single character).
Is it possible to do this in bash or I have to use a program like python to do this?

Comment: Shouldn't it be "greater than *or equal to* two"? Otherwise, `m a` would have to stay `m a`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perl one-liner:

```
echo 'Y M C A' | perl -ple's/\b\w\K\s(?=\w\b)//g'
==> YMCA

echo 't mobile' | perl -ple's/\b\w\K\s(?=\w\b)//g'
==> t mobile
```

This replaces a space when surrounded by a single word character. You can replace `\w` by `[a-zA-Z]` if it's more convenient for you.

Comment: There's also `\pL` aka `\p{Letter}`, Unlike `\w`, this won't compress `1 2 3 4`

Answer (score 2):

This sed one-liner works for given example:

```
sed -r 's/ (\S\S)/_\1/g;s/(\S\S) /\1_/g;s/ //g;s/_/ /g' file
```

Test with your data:

```
kent$  sed -r 's/ (\S\S)/_\1/g;s/(\S\S) /\1_/g;s/ //g;s/_/ /g' f   
YMCA
cambridge ma
dmv office
t mobile
```

I used a place holder in above line, the `_`, if your text has already `_`, you can use `\x99`,  in visible char.

Comment: simple and efficient, nice

Answer (score 1):

With any awk in any shell on any UNIX system:

```
$ awk '{out=$1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) {out = out (length($(i-1)$i)==2 ? "" : OFS) $i} print out}' file
YMCA
cambridge ma
dmv office
t mobile
```